# Integration with indicator function $I(x=0)$

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

It is assumed that in one of the lectures,

$$\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-iux}\,I(x=0)\,dx = 1$$

Shouldn't this formula be equal to $\mathbf{dx}$ instead of $\mathbf{1}$? This formula has non-zero value only when $x=0$, so $$e^{-iu0}\,1\,dx = \mathbf{dx}$$ will be the final result of that integration instead of $\mathbf{1}$. If I am missing any concept, please let me know.

Comment: this "formula" is an abuse of notation and it is just a kind of "definition", so it doesn't have logic itself

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks for the reply. Is this formula a widely known definition? It actually comes from the spectral density of white noise process, and I saw this for the first time.

Comment: this formula is related to the theory of distributions, but I dont remember now how exactly is defined this kind of abuse of notation, probably it is some kind of distributional derivative or so.

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks Masacroso. Guess I will have to look up distribution part.